Anthropic API request stalling out
I'm working in Next.js and making a request to the Claude API, but my request stalls out (i.e., in the console, it shows as pending). Here's a relevant code snippet for the front-end "imageUpload" component:
  const extractTextFromImage = async () => {
    if (!photo) return;
  
    try {
      setText('Loading...'); // Show a loading message
  
      const base64Image = photo.split(',')[1]; // Remove the 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' prefix
  
      const controller = new AbortController();
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 30000); // Set a timeout of 30 seconds
  
      const apiResponse = await fetch('/api/generate', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: base64Image, // Send only the base64 string
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
        },
        signal: controller.signal, // Pass the AbortController signal to the fetch request
      });
  
      clearTimeout(timeoutId); // Clear the timeout if the request completes before the timeout
  
      if (!apiResponse.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${apiResponse.status}`);
      }
  
      const data = await apiResponse.json();
      setText(data.content[0].text || 'No text found');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error extracting text:', error);
      if ((error as Error).name === 'AbortError') {
        setText('Request timed out. Please try again.'); // Show a timeout error message
      } else {
        setText('Error extracting text');
      }
    }
  };

And here's the relevant code from my API endpoint:
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import Anthropic from '@anthropic-ai/sdk';
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http';

const anthropic = new Anthropic();

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const body = await parseRequestBody(req);
      const { image } = body;

      if (!image) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Image data is required' });
      }

      const apiKey = process.env.ANTHROPIC_API_KEY;
      if (!apiKey) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Anthropic API key is not set' });
      }
      console.log('About to send');
      const message = await anthropic.messages.create({
        model: 'claude-3-opus-20240229',
        max_tokens: 1024,
        messages: [
          {
            role: 'user',
            content: [
              {
                type: 'text',
                text: 'You are an AI assistant that can extract information from pilot logbook pages. When provided with an image of a logbook page, you should respond with the extracted information in a table format.',
              },
              {
                type: 'image',
                source: {
                  type: 'base64',
                  media_type: 'image/jpeg', // Adjust the media type based on the uploaded image format
                  data: image,
                },
              },
              {
                type: 'text',
                text: 'Please extract the relevant information from this pilot logbook page and provide the response in a table format.',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      });

      console.log('message: ', message);
      res.status(200).json(message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error processing image:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to process image' });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
};

async function parseRequestBody(req: IncomingMessage & { body?: any }): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body += chunk.toString();
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      try {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}


export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '10mb',
    },
  },
};

I tried sending a photo to the Claude API to turn it into a digitized table (something along the lines of a spreadsheet), but the request just stalled out (it was listed as "pending" for a very long time and never made it to the Claude API, per the API usage logs provided by the Claude console).
